# Implementing undo feature: how to measure memory consumption of JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, memory

We need to implement undo functionality for a web editor and want to test how deep the undo history could reasonably go.

The undo data model is a JavaScript array containing 1+ jQuery objects, each of which could contain multiple Base64 images.

How can you measure memory usage of JavaScript objects? Is it possible to monitor memory usage from Chrome?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: @Dom this is an awesome link. Could you post as an answer so you can receive credit?

Comment: Thanks. Sure, I'll follow up in the morning. I recommend also taking a look at this post as well. In particular, the memory metrics section: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#memory

Comment: To add up , Here below is the link which has details about the views which would help you in heap profiling and also uncover memory leaks in an application. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling

Comment: Not really an answer to the current question but, don't store as base64 (34% bigger than binary), always use Blobs and if you need to store a lot, then consider using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), even if it's for a short time only. This will save on disk rather than in memory.

Comment: @Kaiido you're awesome, thanks for the great tip!

Comment: @Dom friendly reminder if you want the bounty! it ends soon!

Comment: @Kaiido it seems IndexedDB browser support is quite good: https://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb. so this does seem like a much better solution for the core problem of implementing undo. thanks again!

Comment: @Crashalot unfortunately I'm not able to write up an answer in time, so feel free to award someone else! Hopefully you found the answer you were looking for!

Comment: @dom was just waiting for you, thanks for the answer! shame you won't get credit.

Comment: @Kaiido Hi again, have you had issues with user permissions and IndexDB? That's our big concern with using IndexDB vs. browser memory. This SO answer is pretty outdated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872202/indexeddb-user-permissions

Comment: No I never faced this prompt, nor had any client complain about such a prompt (we use it in a systematic way on our product). To make your life simpler, you may want to use localforage library, by Mozilla, which handles very well a lot of cases and fallsback nicely to what it can.

Comment: @Kaiido OK thanks. do you guys use localforage as well or directly work against IndexDB?

Comment: We use localforage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome have a great tool for that. It's based on RAIL model and allows you to quickly detect leaks and even bloats. Just go to chrome's Task Manager (shift + esc) and enable `Javascript memory`. This tool saved my life, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are built in tools in **Chrome DevTools** that allow you to inspect memory usage.

You can access them via the **task manager** (`Shift+Esc` or `Main Menu > More tools > Task manager`) then right click on `Header` and enable `JavaScript Memory`

You can find more info there:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#memory